# Should I delete this answer that maybe should have been an edit?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, design

I'm not sure if I am being out of line with my community wiki answer to this.  I basically copied the other one and edited it, but didn't think an edit would get my point across.  Should I delete this, am I being a total jerk?

[Justifying a memory upgrade, take 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/134960/justifying-a-memory-upgrade-take-2)

Comment: Went with Brandon, deleted it, and made it an edit. Thanks for taking the time to look at it.  If you someone is still curious they can just look at the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the majority of your post is the exact same content.

You could either edit his post to include your input or just leave a comment on his answer and let him edit what he wants. Having to read the same thing twice just to look for minor differences is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's fine the way it is, especially since you set it CW so you can't be accused of rep whoring.